# Git bash can not identify USB flash drives

Tags: git

I use git bash under windowsXP system.I try to enter my USB Disk by entering "cd G:" in git bash,but it apears that "sh.exe : cd : g:: No such file or directory".

I can open my USB Disk under my system.

What's wrong with it ?How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git bash uses the `/x` form to identify the root of drives, instead of `X:`. Doing `cd /g` should work correctly (you'll likely see similar paths while working within it).

I believe this is just how bash handles the drives on Windows (it is used through all the versions of git bash I've used, on XP through 7).

Comment: I have tried ,but it dosen't work well，else.Each time it can't find the USB disk,i will restart my git ,then it can identify.

Answer (score 20):

Gina, the real answer is in your comment above. You have to close down not just any Git bash window, but ALL git bash windows and then re-open one of them. At that point, `cd /f` will work. By the way, `cd F:` also works, as the bash terminal converts that to /f. I just confirmed this on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: And do not forget to kill any ssh-agent ... I lost some time to find this

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to close all bash windows, or that doesn't help, you can share the drive, and access the network share. Worked for me, usb stick at `//localhost/usb` works fine, closing bash didn't.

Comment: how do you create such a Windows share?

Answer (score -1):

you can go down to the root of your computer by using the "cd .." command until you can go any further the copy the path from your flash drive and past it in the bash command. eg "cd D:\website" where D is the external flash drive.